# using @Transactional for thread safety

Tags: java, spring, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

I have a question about how @Transactional annotation alone manages code and transactions execution. Given a correctly setup Spring application and the following code:

```
@Transactional
public void withdraw(int amount) {
    if(isEnoughFunds(amount)) {
        decreaseFunds(amount);
    }
}
```

Is it possible for the following scenario to occur:

- funds == 100; amount == 100
- thread A enters withdraw / transaction A starts
- thread A executes isEnoughFunds which evaluates to true
- thread B enters withdraw / transaction B starts
- thread B executes isEnoughFunds which evaluates to true
- thread A executes decreaseFunds / thread A locks db record
- thread B waits for thread A to commit transaction and release write lock
- thread A exits withdraw / transaction A commits
- thread B executes decreaseFunds / thread B locks db record
- thread B exits withdraw / transaction B commits
- funds == -100

If this is possible how would you prevent that?

Comment: the annotation just says to wrap this in a transaction. the database isolation level determines how much interleaving occurs.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible, depending on the isolation level. To prevent it, you can explicitly obtain a read lock from the database before calling ifEnoughFunds(). The lock will be released at the end of the transaction. In this scenario, thread B will always wait for thread's A transaction to commit before checking.

Comment: can you explain this further with a code example how to do this in spring and hibernate? thank you!